# Переход между двумя view контроллерами через Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Здравствуйте. Я только начал изучать obj c и как первую программу я делаю переход между двумя вьюхами через  Navigation Controller . Кнопки находятся в navigation bar.Вот что у меня  в  файлах:

UntitledAppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

       RootViewController *rootViewController=[[RootViewController alloc] init];
       UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]                 
       initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
       self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;

        [view release];
        [label release];
        [button release];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         return YES;
      }
```

RootViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.title=@"My View Controller";
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;

   UIBarButtonItem *item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
   initWithTitle:@"next view"   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
   target:self  action:@selector(secondPage:)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=item;

   [item release];

    }
 -(void)secondPage:(id)sender
{
    UIBarButtonItem *item=(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    if(self.secondViewController==nil)
    {
        SecondViewController *secondView=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
        self.secondViewController=secondView;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Cоответственно, есть файл  SecondViewController.m,но пока он пустой

Выдает ошибку что request for member  "secondViewController" in something not a structure or union

Все .h файлы я подсоединил. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, что здесь не так?

Comment: У Вас нигде не видно как реализованы визуальные представления. Вы используете .xib, storyboard'ы или создаете View руками?

Comment: руками все в didFinishLaunchingWithOptions прописано

 CGRect  bounds=[window bounds];
 UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
 [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
 [window addSubview:view];

Comment: SecondViewController точно наследник UIViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы что, из прошлого? Поубирайте свои release. Уже 2 года, как они не используются.

```
-(void)secondPage:(id)sender {
    if(!secondViewController)  {
        SecondViewController *secondViewController=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону:

```
popViewControllerAnimated:
pushViewController:animated:
```